# pyCharm warning in django code: Unresolved attribute reference 'user' for 'WSGIRequest'

Tags: python, django, pycharm

in my brandnew PyCharm professional edition I get the warning "*Unresolved attribute reference 'user' for 'WSGIRequest'*". The warning occurs in the first line of `MyClass.post()` (see code below).

```
from django.views import generic
from django.db import models
from django.http.request import HttpRequest
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class CustomUser( AbstractUser ):
    emailname = models.CharField()


class Invoice( models.Model ):
    posted = models.DateField()


class BaseView ( generic.DetailView ):

    model = Invoice

    def __int__( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        super().__init__( *args, **kwargs )
        # some more code


class MyClass( BaseView ):

    def __int__( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        super().__init__( *args, **kwargs )
        # some more code

    def post( self, request: HttpRequest, *args, **kwargs ):
        context = { 'curr_user': request.user, } # <-- Unresolved attribute reference 'user' for class 'WSGIRequest'
        # some more code
        html_page = 'mypage.html'
        return render( request, html_page, context )
```

`user` ist a `CustomUser` object. Debugging shows, that `user` is a known attribute in `CustomUser` and the code works well, 'curr_user' in `context` is the expected one. Other attributes of `request` like `request.path` or `request.REQUEST` are not warned. Django support is enabled.

I work with PyCharm 2023.2.5 (Professional Edition), Windows 11

Can anybody help? What is my mistake?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.user` is not necessarily a thing for all requests (it depends on you having a middleware that injects it), hence it's not shown as necessarily existing.

If you need it to, you can of course add a

```
class HttpRequestWithUser(HttpRequest):
    user: CustomUser
```

class that you use for your type annotations.